# Multiple event on single element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, look like this

```
$(".btn-vote").click(function(){
//bla bla
});
$(".btn-vote").dblclick(function(){
//bla bla
});
```

How can I compact it? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method :

```
$(".btn-vote").on('click dblclick',function(){
  //bla bla
});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much